# How can i have both a controller and an apicontroller in my project Symfony

Tags: rest, symfony, controller

I already have a symfony project that I just finished, which is a website.Now I would add an api-rest in this project, but I do not know how to add my api controllers, since in my project I have several bundles and each bundle has its controller.
Now how to add an API controller for each bundle ?
Here is a screen shot of the tree of my symfony project:

[image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 1]

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have multiple options. Inside each bundle make a folder called API and then place the controller in there. Or for each controller make another controller called 'ApiMyController.php' or if you don't want new controllers, inside your existing prefix routes with '/api/' as all API routes should be

Comment: @MylesK, you understood well. Since i'm new with api rest so i do not know it's the most adequate solution ?

Comment: Look into https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle you can choose to expose your route